# Facebook Social Comments Plugin not able to link to post content

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-comments

I would be grateful for some assistance with Facebook Social Plugins.

I have a bunch of portfolio items on my website that are rendered with a fb-comments-plugin at the bottom of the page.

At the top of the page (in the header) is a "like" button that is designed to cover the whole site (i.e. if you "like" the site - click the "like" at the top of the page). But, if you want to "like" the post - click the "like" alongside the post.

Anyway, every now and again - the comments plugin on one of the portfolio items indicates to me:

"Warning: {url} is not accessible"

This does not appear to be consistent across all items. For instance:

http://www.greensidefilms.com.au/portfolio/bride/

does not work, but:

http://www.greensidefilms.com.au/portfolio/twilight/

does work...

Confused I am, seeing as it is exactly the same code generating all these pages.

Is there something not quite right with the og meta tags that is causing the plugin to be confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those links you provided are dead

I had some trouble when I first started working with the Facebook social plugins and found that the problem you are describing is with the APP ID, it is designed to work with a domain in your case yes it is the same domain however you should double check if the same APP ID is being used in all your plugins, using the wrong APP ID will cause that kind of behavior.

Comment: thx... yeah I ended up hiding those pages. Going to chalk this one up to experience. All the visible pages on the portfolio seems to now be working so have to put this down to an intermittent glitch. Thx for the hints anyway.